# Changing the color of different intent in an application

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to change the color of different intent in an application.Like for one intent action bar color is red and for some other intent the action bar color is yellow.
Here is my AndroidMenifest.xml in which i changed the text of label.
But how to change background of that text background same as of main screen of application[image]. [image][image][image]

Look i did the changes but its not working.
    `package com.example.android.miwok;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout 
file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);

// Set a click listener on that View
    numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // The code in this method will be executed when the numbers View is 
clicked on.
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
NumbersActivity.class);
            startActivity(numbersIntent);
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NumbersActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("toolbarColor", Color.BLUE);
        }
    });
    TextView family = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.family);

// Set a click listener on that View
    family.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // The code in this method will be executed when the family View is 
clicked on.
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent familyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
FamilyMembersActivity.class);
             startActivity(familyIntent);
        }
    });
    TextView colors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colors);

// Set a click listener on that View
    colors.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // The code in this method will be executed when the colors View is 
clicked on.
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent colorsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
ColorsActivity.class);
            startActivity(colorsIntent);
        }
    });
    TextView pharses = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phrases);

// Set a click listener on that View
    pharses.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // The code in this method will be executed when the numbers View is 
clicked on.
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent pharsesIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
PharsesActivity.class);
            startActivity(pharsesIntent);
        }
    });
}
public void openNumberList(View view){
    Intent viewNumber= new Intent(this,NumbersActivity.class);
    startActivity(viewNumber);
}
public void openFamilyMembersList(View view){
    Intent viewFamily= new Intent(this,FamilyMembersActivity.class);
    startActivity(viewFamily);
}
public void openPharsesList(View view){
    Intent viewPharses= new Intent(this,PharsesActivity.class);
    startActivity(viewPharses);
}
public void openColorsList(View view){
    Intent viewColor= new Intent(this,ColorsActivity.class);
    startActivity(viewColor);
}
}
```

`

Comment: Don't share your code's image, just copy it to here...

Comment: ok will take care next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want? If so, follow my step. I will show you how to do.
[image: show_demo]

1. First, declare the style of each activity.[res/values/styles.xml]

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>

       <!-- other styles ... -->

       <style name="NumbersBg" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
           <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryNumbers</item>
           <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkNumbers</item>
           <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
       </style>

       <style name="FamilyMembersBg" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
           <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryFamilyMembers</item>
           <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkFamilyMembers</item>
           <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
       </style>

       <style name="ColorsBg" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
           <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryColors</item>
           <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkColors</item>
           <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
       </style>

       <style name="PhrasesBg" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
           <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryPhrases</item>
           <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkPhrases</item>
           <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
       </style>

   </resources>
   ```

   by the way, the colors mentioned above should be declared earlier in colors.xml[res/values/colors.xml]:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>

       <!-- other colors ... -->

       <!-- Numbers -->
       <color name="colorPrimaryNumbers">#fd8d28</color>
       <color name="colorPrimaryDarkNumbers">#AE611C</color>
       <!-- Family Members -->
       <color name="colorPrimaryFamilyMembers">#3b913c</color>
       <color name="colorPrimaryDarkFamilyMembers">#2C6B2C</color>
       <!-- Colors -->
       <color name="colorPrimaryColors">#87149e</color>
       <color name="colorPrimaryDarkColors">#4C0C59</color>
       <!-- Phrases -->
       <color name="colorPrimaryPhrases">#26afc8</color>
       <color name="colorPrimaryDarkPhrases">#186D7C</color>

   </resources>
   ```
2. Quote the styles you declared before in AndroidManifest.xml.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest>
       <application>

           <!-- other activities ... -->

           <activity
               android:name=".NumbersActivity"
               android:theme="@style/NumbersBg" />

           <activity
               android:name=".FamilyMembersActivity"
               android:theme="@style/FamilyMembersBg" />

           <activity
               android:name=".ColorsActivity"
               android:theme="@style/ColorsBg" />

           <activity
               android:name=".PhrasesActivity"
               android:theme="@style/PhrasesBg" />

       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```
3. run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the color as an extra to the activity.

```
Intent intent = ..;
intent.putExtra("toolbarColor", Color.BLUE);
```

And in the activity you want the toolbar color to change

```
int color = getIntent().getExtra("toolbarColor");
toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
```